# Create standard CRUD actions in one Rails controller for inherit it for other controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, crud

I saw in one project on rails Standard CRUD in main controller in namespace,
how i can do it in my projects? (how check name of resource, and how organize `routes.rb`)

Comment: Can you please be more specific so that i can help you?

Comment: for examle in simple project all CUD actions i want define in ApplicationController, and in specific controller redefine some action if i need, but how i can model name of model what i use at now, and how i can organize rourers.rb in this case?

Comment: @ОлегКулаков, there is a gem for it - https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources, but it is no longer actively maintained by the original author. IMHO, it is not a good idea to use some kind of common actions and modify some of them in the particular controller. Time goes by, the application is getting bigger, and you are adding more and more complex logic to the common actions, instead of just write different actions in different controllers :)

Comment: @Vasilisa, yes, i think you are right. Thanks